# Json data remove unwanted elements

Tags: c#, json, xml, tags

I have the following in some json I have converted from XML:

```
"ForSaleStatus":{"items":{"item":{"label":"Not For Sale","value":"2"}}}
```

This was some xml an application generated from a dropdown. I want to convert it to this in C#:

```
"ForSaleStatus":"2"
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var xml = i;
var root = XElement.Parse(xml);

// remove ALL empty elements such as <items/>
root.Descendants().Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)).Remove();

// convert the node to JSON for easier processing
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(root);
```

Can anyone think of a way of converting the json or am I better off going back to the XML and working on that?

The XML looks like this:

```
<ForSaleStatus>
  <items>
    <item>
       <label>Not For Sale</label>
       <value>2</value>
    </item>
  </items>
</ForSaleStatus>
```

Comment: Can you provide the original xml from the application?

Comment: have edited the post. I realised this was required after I first submitted it. Perhaps you commented while I was editing? Can you see it now? I guess it's probably more sensible to strip them out of the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to extract the values you want and just construct the json from that :

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    [root.Name.ToString()] = root.XPathSelectElement("items/item/value").Value
});
```

If that doesn't compile for you, use this older syntax :

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { root.Name.ToString(), root.XPathSelectElement("items/item/value").Value }
});
```

---

Edit: in case you need values from all the items :

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root
    .XPathSelectElements("items/item")
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.XPathSelectElement("label").Value,
        x => x.XPathSelectElement("value").Value
    ));
```

Comment: Many thanks, yes, that will do. I will re-work my code and just strip out the values I want and build it that way. cheers.

Comment: This is just a hard-coded solution for this problem only. Btw, does the `ForSaleStatus` contains more than 1 item and you needed all of them?

Comment: Thanks, that's great. ForSaleStatus only ever has a single item because it's a single select drop down list that generates the data. In this job there's no point in making the code too elegant because all I need is a one off hit to extract the data. But thanks very much for the help.